# Заменить «Присоединяйтесь! Это не займёт больше минуты: [Регистрация]»

Tags: предложение, локализация

Баннер для новых посетителей:

> Stack Overflow на русском — сайт вопросов и ответов для программистов. Присоединяйтесь! Это не займёт больше минуты: [Регистрация]

не упоминает явно что человеку это даст. Можно к примеру так написать:

> Stack Overflow на русском — сайт вопросов и ответов для программистов. Столкнулись с проблемой, найдите ответ: [Искать]

<sup>где кнопка [Искать] ведёт на страницу с Google поиском для [ru.SO], [пример](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83+%D0%B2+%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5).</sup>

или *"Поделитесь решением интересной вам проблемы или задайте новый вопрос [Задать вопрос]"*

Сейчас баннер призывает тратить время на скучную деятельность (регистрация), не понятно для чего. Слово регистрация не должно возникать, до тех пор пока человек не нажал кнопку [Отправить] в своём уже напечатанном StackOveflow вопросе, ответе (тогда имеет значение, что регистрация меньше минуты).

Конкретная формулировка призыва к действию может быть другой, если она упоминает возможную выгоду для нового участника и соответствующее действие не дальше одного нажатия на кнопку.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Призыв должен быть мотивированным. И с тем, что нужно направлять в поиск, а не на создание нового ответа, полностью согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Не забывайте, что *Stack Overflow на русском* есть лишь локализованная версия семейства сайтов Stack Exchange. А это значит, что для полноценной замены какого-либо функционала идеи надо проталкивать через *Meta Stack Exchange*. Конечно, в ряде случаев мы можем просто подправить перевод и сделать из "black" - "белый", или "красный", или любой другой, но не "чёрный". Всё это искажает смысл, то есть логика внутри остаётся прежней, а пользователь видит совсем не то, что заложил в движок разработчик. Я категорически против такого подхода к исправлению ошибок движка.

Теперь к самой идее. Вы привели текст баннеров, но не привели общего вида страницы с этими баннерами. И если на них посмотреть в контексте, то будет видно, что поиск и так доступен новым пользователям и даже возможность задать вопрос без регистрации имеется:

> [image: Большой баннер]

Да, баннер большой, но есть кнопка сворачивания, и он таким образом может быть уменьшен:

> [image: Мини баннер]

Нажатие на крестик и вовсе позволяет его убрать:

> [image: Нет баннера]

И здесь уже бОльшую часть занимает строка поиска, которого Вам так не доставало.

А вот скучная регистрация или нет, это уже не важно. Для серьёзного участия в жизни сайта она нужна и то, что исходный баннер большой и всячески предлагает зарегистрироваться, а не просто искать и задавать вопросы без регистрации, говорит о том, что менеджмент *Stack Overflow* заинтересован в первую очередь именно в новых зарегистрированных участниках. Поиском же обычно приходят на SO из гугла, а задают вопросы без регистрации достаточно редко (статистику по SEDE не собирал, говорю на основании личных наблюдений).

В итоге: менять что-то в переводе через transifex здесь ошибочное решение (да и не получится так), а за предложением смены логики - на MSE.